# Unit test cannot get the expected result, code show as below

Tags: scala

This is my code, which convert a date time to epoch timestamp.The logic is if the time is local date time then doSomething, else, doSomething.
Success case works good

```
time_to_epoch(List(JString("2000-01-01"), JString("yyyy-MM-dd"))) shouldEqual JString("946684800")
time_to_epoch(List(JString("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z"), JString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))) shouldEqual JString("1380480379")
```

But the failure cases cant get expected result, error is "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-06-21-10-19-22' could not be parsed at index 19", why cant I get JNothing? How to resolve this error？

```
time_to_epoch(List(JString("2016-06-21-10-19-22"), JString("YYYY-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss a"))) shouldEqual JNothing
```

```
def time_to_epoch(params: List[JValue]): JValue = params match {

      case _ :: _ :: Nil =>
        time_to_epoch(params ::: List(JString("UTC")))
      case a :: b :: c :: Nil =>

        val jdOpt = for {
          JString(timestamp) <- coerce.toString(a)
          JString(pattern) <- coerce.toString(b)

          formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
          df = formatter.parseBest(timestamp, LocalDateTime.from(_), LocalDate.from(_))

          jd1 <- if (df.isInstanceOf[LocalDateTime]) {
            val res = df.asInstanceOf[LocalDateTime].toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(String.valueOf(ZoneId.of("UTC").getRules.getOffset(LocalDateTime.now))))
            Try(JString(res.getEpochSecond.toString)).toOption
          } else {
            Try(JString(df.asInstanceOf[LocalDate].atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant.getEpochSecond.toString)).toOption
          }
        } yield jd1

        jdOpt.getOrElse(JNothing)
      case _ => JNothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is that the exception is being thrown in `parseBest` which is outside any `Try` so it is not being caught.

The use of `asInstanceOf` is also dangerous, so use `match` instead:

```
def time_to_epoch(params: List[JValue]): JValue = params match {
  case _ :: _ :: Nil =>
    time_to_epoch(params ::: List(JString("UTC")))
  case JString(timestamp) :: JString(pattern) :: JString(tz) :: Nil =>
    Try {
      val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
      val df = formatter.parseBest(timestamp, LocalDateTime.from _, LocalDate.from _)

      df match {
        case ldt: LocalDateTime =>
          val res = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(String.valueOf(ZoneId.of(tz).getRules.getOffset(LocalDateTime.now))))
          JString(res.getEpochSecond.toString)
        case ld: LocalDate =>
          JString(ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(tz)).toInstant.getEpochSecond.toString)
        case _ =>
          JNothing
      }
    }.getOrElse(JNothing)
  case _ =>
    JNothing
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for your reply,  if I want to keep this part ```JString(timestamp) <- coerce.toString(a)
          JString(pattern) <- coerce.toString(b)```, how can I do that?

Comment: You would have to match on the bare values again and restore the `for` loop. The main thing is wrap the whole thing in a `Try`, and use `match` rather than `[as][is]InstanceOf`

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, since date only have LocalDateTime and LocalDate two types, what should be the case for ```case _ =>
          JNothing```?

Comment: I was just being cautious by adding the catch-all; I don't know the libraries well enough to know whether there might be some other type returned!